# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'

Tags: python, module, pytorch, attributes, attributeerror

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z86j0.png)
https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning

I am trying to clone my voice using ML. I am following : https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning repository. But at the third step of Setup that is when I run the command python demo_cli.py I am getting the error: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'. My python version is 3.7.9 and my machine do not have a gpu.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`os.add_dll_directory`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory) was introduced in Python 3.8. It's not available in your version, Python 3.7.

To use that function, you'll need to upgrade to Python 3.8 or later.

Since it's being used from within PyTorch, it's possible that this is due to an incompatible version of PyTorch being used. Downgrading your PyTorch version may solve that.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what is causing my script to call the attribute `add_dll_directory`? For me, the line `import geopandas` causes the error, but I don't know why, or if it can be avoided while accomplishing the same thing.