# importing geopandas throws error `module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'`

Tags: python, dll, environment, arcgis, geopandas

`enter code here`when importing geopandas: `import geopandas as gpd` error `module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'` is thrown.

geopandas version: 0.9.0

python version: 3.7

operating system: Windows 10

**Constraint:**

I am working on a computer which blocks the installation of Python except that which comes as part of a ArcPro (GIS) installation. Therefore I cannot update my Python installation to meet the requirements of packages.

I recognize that this question has been asked elsewhere like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75794403/attributeerror-module-os-has-no-attribute-add-dll-directory). This response taught me that `add_dll_dirrectory` is not supported  by python 3.7, which is my version, so that is likely my problem.

**Attempts:**

1. Downgrade geopandas to v0.10.2 (last version compatible with Python 3.7). This had no effect on the result.

**Question:**

What is actually causing this error? Can I avoid it and still make used of geopandas given my constraints?

Here is the full error message:

[image: Full error message]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message and stack trace?

Comment: @Brian61354270 I have included a screenshot of the whole error message above. I am just looking into accessing a stack trace. However, is it still useful if my script only has one line `import geopandas`?

Comment: fyi [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11082165). But base on that screenshot, the problem is in `fiona` (not `geopandas` itself). Evidently, the version of fiona you have installed isn't compatible with Python 3.7 (since its trying to call a function that was added in Python 3.8). Curiously the latest release on PyPI states that it *is* compatible with Python 3.7. It's possible that the maintainer didn't notice that it actually requires Python 3.8+ when run on Windows.

Comment: Your options likely are 1) try to downgrade fiona to a version that is compatible with Python 3.7, 2) upgrade to Python 3.8+ (which would be a good idea anyway, since 3.7 has reached EOL. The oldest version of Python still receiving bugfix maintenance is 3.11), or 3) switch to an OS other than Windows.

Comment: Ahah! yes downgrading fiona solved the issue. Thank you. Turns out I had several versions installed (one by pip and one by conda) the lesser of the versions was still compatible with my Python installation. I wish I could upgrade my Python instead but the way my computer is configured it doesn't seem that I can.